# (Linear Algebra) How to prove this?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is invertible, and is $n\times n$ matrix. And $A^{ad}$ means adjoint matrix of $A$.

(1) $|A^{ad}|=|A|^{n-1} (n\geq 3)$

(2) $(A^{-1})^{ad}=(A^{ad})^{-1}$

I tried to use $AA^{ad}=|A|I=A^{ad}A$, but I'm not sure if this is right.

Comment: Yes, it's right. Edit to show your work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's right. We claim that :

> **Lemma 1.** (1) is valid for any $n\times n$ matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$.

PROOF. (i) If $\boldsymbol{A}$ is invertable, then $\boldsymbol{A}^*=|\boldsymbol{A}|\boldsymbol{A}^{-1} $.

Thus
$$\left|\boldsymbol{A}^*\right|=\left||\boldsymbol{A}|\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}\right|=\left|\boldsymbol{A}\right|^n\left|\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}\right|=\left|\boldsymbol{A}\right|^{n-1}.$$
(ii) If $\boldsymbol{A}$ is singular, there exsit two invertable matrices $\boldsymbol{P},\boldsymbol{Q}$, and $r<n$ such that
$$\boldsymbol{A}=\boldsymbol{P}\left[
 \begin{array}{cc}
 \boldsymbol{I}_r& \boldsymbol{0}\\
 \boldsymbol{0}& \boldsymbol{0}
 \end{array}
 \right]\boldsymbol{Q}=:\boldsymbol{P}\boldsymbol{B}\boldsymbol{Q}.$$
Now $\left|\boldsymbol{B}^*\right|=0$ implies that
$$\left|\boldsymbol{A}^*\right|=\left|\boldsymbol{Q}^*\right|\left|\boldsymbol{B}^*\right|\left|\boldsymbol{P}^*\right|=0=\left|\boldsymbol{A}\right|^{n-1}.$$
This completes the proof.$\quad\square$

> **Lemma 2.** $\left(\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}\right)^*=\left(\boldsymbol{A}^*\right)^{-1}$.

PROOF. The fact
$$\boldsymbol{A}^*\left(\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}\right)^*=\left(\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}\boldsymbol{A}\right)^*=\boldsymbol{I}_n^*=\boldsymbol{I}_n$$
finishes the proof.$\quad\square$

Comment: why $||A||$ changed to $|A|^{n}$ at the first proof?

Comment: @PhilliP That's because you should extract $|A|$ from the $n$ rows.

Comment: @RocHong I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean... What does it mean that I should extract $|A|$ from the $n$ rows?